# How to connect an Arduino Uno to an Android phone via USB cable?

Tags: arduino, usb

Is it possible to set up communication between an Arduino Uno and an Android phone using a wire that directly connects the Android phone and the Arduino?

Comment: I'm not going to go any more in depth than this, so I'll leave it as a comment, but my gut reaction was a 2 way modem on a headset connection.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? You might choose for a bluetooth/wifi connection instead.

Comment: i wanna control this arduino with anothe mobile #FuaZe

Comment: You have to use the @ symbol, not the # symbol to talk to someone :-)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst your question would be better suited to the [Arduino StackExchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions) site, I shall attempt to answer it nevertheless. Below is the method that I have used in the past, however, there are, obviously, more than one way to skin a cat... For example the same question was asked a few years ago on EE.SE, [Connect Android device to Arduino Uno via USB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94272/connect-android-device-to-arduino-uno-via-usb).

The answer to your question may be found here, [Android USB host + Arduino: How to communicate without rooting our Android tablet or phone](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549). However there are some pre-requisites for the Android device that you are intending to use:

> **You will require an Android device that supports USB host mode as well
>   as the USB host API**. Most Android 3.1+ tablets will suffice (some may
>   require an USB OTG adapter). Also, the Galaxy Nexus has host mode
>   enabled and matches the requirements (you will need an USB OTG adapter
>   however).

I shall quote the information from the above page, in the case of link death.

> This example consists of two parts:
>
> - **The Android application that makes use of the USB API**
>
> A simple Android
>   app that let’s you regulate the brightness of an LED on the Arduino
>   using a slider. It also features a button to “enumerate” the USB
>   device.
>
> - **Firmware for the Arduino that does some serial I/O with the
>     Android app**
>
> Very basic firmware for the Arduino. An interrupt is
>   generated when a new byte is received. The received data controls the
>   brightness of the Arduino’s on-board LED. (implemented via
>   usleep-style software pwm in the main loop).

The Arduino Code:

```
int main(void) {
    //initialization
    initIO();
    uart_init();
    sei();

    uint8_t i = 0;
    volatile uint8_t pause;

    for(;;){//this is the main loop
        pause = data;
        PORTB |= (1 << LED);
        for(i = 0; i < pause; i++)
            _delay_us(10);
        PORTB &= ~(1 << LED);
        for(i = 0; i < 255-pause; i++)
            _delay_us(10);
    }
}
```

The Arduino Interrupt routine:

```
ISR(USART_RX_vect) {//attention to the name and argument here, won't work otherwise
    data = UDR0;//UDR0 needs to be read
}
```

The Android  source code is available here: [UsbController.tar.gz](http://android.serverbox.ch/wp-content/UsbController.tar.gz)*.

> - You may need to change the PID value in UsbControllerActivity.java on line 38, if you have an Arduino Uno Rev3 or higher. You can check the VID/PID value with ‘lsusb’ after connecting the Arduino to your computer.

Most of the code is pretty standard, however, it is worth paying attention to the following `UsbRunnable` class:

```
private class UsbRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final UsbDevice mDevice;

    UsbRunnable(UsbDevice dev) {
        mDevice = dev;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {//here the main USB functionality is implemented
        UsbDeviceConnection conn = mUsbManager.openDevice(mDevice);
        if (!conn.claimInterface(mDevice.getInterface(1), true)) {
            return;
        }
        // Arduino USB serial converter setup
        conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
        conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0, new byte[] { (byte) 0x80,
                0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 7, 0);

        UsbEndpoint epIN = null;
        UsbEndpoint epOUT = null;

        UsbInterface usbIf = mDevice.getInterface(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < usbIf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
            if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
                    epIN = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
                else
                    epOUT = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
            }
        }

        for (;;) {// this is the main loop for transferring
            synchronized (sSendLock) {//ok there should be a OUT queue, no guarantee that the byte is sent actually
                try {
                    sSendLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    if (mStop) {
                        mConnectionHandler.onUsbStopped();
                        return;
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, new byte[] { mData }, 1, 0);

            if (mStop) {
                mConnectionHandler.onUsbStopped();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> After the USB interface has been claimed the Arduino USB serial
>   converter is initialized by issuing the following control transfers:
>
> ```
> conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
> conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0, new byte[] { (byte) 0x80,
>                 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 7, 0);
> ```
>
> The first call sets the control line state, the second call sets the
>   line encoding (9600, 8N1). For communication, an additional thread is
>   used to send data without blocking the Activity’s main UI thread. By
>   notifying sSendLock of the UsbController the data will be transferred.
>   After submission, the thread will go into “wait” again. This way, even
>   if submission takes more time than expected, the Activity’s main
>   thread will not be blocked and hence the app will not become
>   unresponsive.